# Ubuntu 20.04 LTS live: Low screen resolution available

Tags: lenovo, display-resolution, live-environment, intel-hd

I use windows and want to install Ubuntu 20.04 on my Lenovo ThinkPad t440, so tried Ubuntu live environment to know do I like it or no. I saw that the screen resolution is low and the available choice for resolution is almost 400 pixels. Will it get better when I install the OS completely?

GPU: Intel HD Graphics 4400

Comment: We have a T440 running Lubuntu 18.04; max resolution is 1600x900.

Comment: Was it default?